# library for text rendering that supports text-on-path

Tags: python, rendering, text-rendering

I need a good, reliable library or toolchain for programatically rendering text to png, with different sizes, fonts, weights, etc. It also needs to be able to render text in an arc or to a path. I would like it to be fast, because I'd be running it as on a server.

I've tried using SVG and `librsvg`, but that doesn't render `<textPath>` elements.

I've tried `pycairo`, but again, the text to path doesn't work great, and everywhere in the cairo documentation it mentions that text-to-path is a "toy" and shouldn't be used for serious applications.

Python bindings would be best, because the server runs python. But I'll take any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has a SVG module, i believe it supports the textPath element.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qtsvg.html

Comment: yeesh. after a whole day of wading through the (horrible) pyqt4 documentation, I'm getting a segmentation fault for no reason at all when I try to render the svg to a QPainter object. I'll keep at it, though

Comment: finally got it working, but qt doesn't render textPath elements, I guess.