# QSvgRenderer segmentation fault

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, segmentation-fault, pyqt4

I realize specific questions like this aren't great, but I've spent several days trying to puzzle this out. Hopefully someone here can help.

This python code using PyQt4 causes a segmentation fault:

```py
data = """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
          <svg height="1000" width="2000">
              <text>blah</text>
          </svg>"""

svg = QSvgRenderer(QByteArray(data))
qim = QImage(int(width), int(height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
painter = QPainter()

painter.begin(qim)
svg.render(painter)
painter.end()

qim.save('test2.png')
```

The line that causes the fault is `svg.render(painter)`.

The fault points at `libQtGui.so` (so something in `QPainter` or `QImage`).

`svg.isValid()` returns `True`, and `qim.isNull()` returns `False`.

Comment: Could you try coding up the equivalent in C++ to see if it works? That'll tell you whether the error is in Qt or PyQt4. Then, if you don't get a good answer, you can head off to the appropriate mailing list or support forum or whatever they have.

Comment: that's a good idea, I didn't consider that it might be PyQt specific.

Comment: What OS are you running on?
What version of PyQt4 do you have?
Is this coming from a packaged exe made with py2exe or is it just running in the interpreter?

Comment: @Nathan - Linux, the latest (4.6.2, installed with easy_install or synaptic, I forget), and I'm just running through the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only a minor change to make that run (defining width and height), it works for me. Note that I don't see any text but if I swap out data to something I know is valid it works perfectly.  Here's my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from  PyQt4.QtGui import *
from  PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtSvg import *
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = """... (my valid svg) ..."""
    
    svg = QSvgRenderer(QByteArray(data))
    qim = QImage(int(2000), int(1000), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter()

    painter.begin(qim)
    svg.render(painter)
    painter.end()

    print "null:", qim.isNull()
    qim.save('test2.png')
```

Comment: the part I was missing was declaring a `QApplication`. Pretty frustrating, especially since that requirement isn't mentioned anywhere in the `QImage`, `QPainter`, or `QSvgRenderer` documentation that I read.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it draw on a QPixmap instead of a QImage.

Qt does cause segfaults once in a while, I usually just code around them.
Maybe you could rasterize this SVG in Gimp and just load that.

Comment: I get "QPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice". Also, the docs say "QImage is designed and optimized for I/O, and for direct pixel access and manipulation, while QPixmap is designed and optimized for showing images on screen."

Comment: In response to your edit, the reason I'm doing this is to programatically rasterize svg. I don't care about creating a Qt application. I would use `rsvg`, but it doesn't support `<textPath>` elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119882/

Comment: I've never seen a segfault in Qt that wasn't my fault or very obvious (e.g. when they changed the order of initialization generated by `uic`). Note that it's possible, but unlikely. A stacktrace would be useful in this case.

Comment: @colinmarc - `QImage` should be fine whereas `QPixmap` does require a GUI. You should be able to use the SVG Viewer example (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/painting-svgviewer.html) to verify that Qt's SVG handling does what you need.

Comment: Because I thought this thread might be related, and because it would be easy. (http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2008-08/thread00397-0.html)